# Definition of configuration section

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a good definition of what's called configuration section in Asp.Net as I can't find anything about that anywhere. I am not against any links what can help me shed some light on it.

Comment: Are you talking about configSections of web.config? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for, would you be able to sum up the whole idea of having them?

Comment: It's where you can put custom config options for your apps. For example, we put our support email in there and customer specific settings. If one of those settings change, we can just edit the config file instead of redeploying the entire application.

Comment: Please move your comment into answer field so that I can mark it as what I was looking for, Thank you @Steve Greene.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_configuration.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom configuration sections allow you to store application wide settings. They allow you to change the configuration without recompiling and deploying the application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.140).aspx